# Bug in CosmosDB Contains function?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I inserted some data into CosmosDB via the graph api. Due to some of the character limitations in the graph API I'm escaping special characters....so in the json document my 'slash/test' string is saved as 'slash%2Ftest'.  What is strange is that when I use a sql query to search the data it is not returned in some circumstances.
I did some tests:
CONTAINS(LOWER(Name._value), "slash%2" returns the expected results
however
CONTAINS(LOWER(Name._value), "slash%2F") returns nothing.

This feels like a bug to me, but I'd like to verify.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason here is the value 'slash%2Ftest' is inserted literally as is. For instance consider this query:

SELECT 'slash%2Ftest'

{
  "$1": "slash%2Ftest"
}

In order to achieve this, you may want to use the Unicode escape sequence \uxxxx. Something like this:

SELECT 'slash\u002Ftest'

{
  "$1": "slash/test"
]

Comment: I'm doing a literal search on the literal string that was inserted into the document.  I can try the Unicode escape sequence...but this still feels like a bug.

Comment: It's actually not a bug because you're comparing to the lowercase value. If you change your query to CONTAINS(LOWER(Name._value), "slash%2f") it should work (%2F -> %2f).

Comment: Oh, I see!  Thank you for your help!